# Getting the different elements from 2 lists in groovy

Tags: list, jenkins, arraylist, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

i have 2 lists in groovy and im trying to 'filter' one list from the other,and get them into a new list .I'm also doing that in a groovy function for a jenkins pipeline I'm writing. Many thank.

```
l1 = ['abc','def','ghi','jkl']
l2 = ['def','jkl']
def sum = []
for (y in l1) {
  for (x in l2) {
     if (x != y){
       sum = sum + x
     }
  }
}              
print sum
```

Comment: Just use the list `minus` function: `def sum = l1-l2`

Comment: Thank you noam, do you know hot can i print the list? it prints me the object instead of the items in the list.

Comment: What command are you using?

Comment: I eventually got it. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eventually I did this and it worked

```
sum = l1 - l2

print "${sum}" //prints the elements in the array
```